# Converting unsigned char array to signed short in C

Tags: c

I want to convert an array of unsigned char to a signed int!
I've already done some try, and the conversion works for the single element like this:

```
  unsigned char byte[2];
  signed char *valueS[2];
  byte[0] = 0b11110111;
  byte[1] = 0b00001001;

  //Conversion
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
     valueS[i] = (signed char*)&byte[i];
  }

  //Result
  printf("Val 0 -> %d \n", *valueS[0]); // print -9 Correctly
  printf("Val 1 -> %d \n", *valueS[1]); // print 9 Correctly

  //But when i try to print a 16 bit signed
  printf("Int %d \n", *(signed short*)valueS); //It doesn't work! I expected -2295
```

How can i get the 16 bit signed int from that unsigned char array? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is `valueS`?

Comment: Assuming `valueS` is an array of `signed char`, you don't need all the bother of pointers: just do the direct conversion: `printf("Int %d \n", (signed int)valueS[i]);`. (Note: you seem to have forgotten to put the `i` index in!)

Comment: `0b00001001` not a valid integer literal

Comment: ...and your solution is machine endianness dependend;

Comment: `//It doesn't work! I expected -2295` - and what's the actual output?

Comment: I've updated the code with the valueS declaration. I've not forgot the i index, because i want to convert valueS ( signed char array of 2 elements, so 16 bit ) to a signed short value of 16 bit! Actually the output is always different, bu i expect -2295

Comment: `printf("Int %d \n", *(signed short*)valueS);` is UB when alignment is not correct.

Comment: kwroot, "i expect -2295" --> Do you want a result of -2295 even if code is run on a big or little endian machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i get the 16 bit signed int from that unsigned char array?

Supposing you mean you want to obtain the `int16_t` whose representation is byte-for-byte identical to the contents of an arbitrary array of two `unsigned char`, the only conforming approach is to declare an `int16_t` object and copy the array elements to its representation.  You could use the `memcpy()` function to do the copying, or you could do it manually.

For example,

```
#include <stdint.h>

// ...

    unsigned char byte[2] = { 0xF7, 0x05 };
    int16_t my_int;
    unsigned char *ip = (unsigned char *) &my_int;

    ip[0] = byte[0];
    ip[1] = byte[1];
    printf("Int %d \n", my_int);
```

You might see a recommendation to use a pointer aliasing trick to try to reinterpret the bytes of the array *directly* as the representation of an integer.  That would take a form similar to your code example, but such an approach is non-conforming, and formally it yields undefined behavior.  You may access the representation of an object of any type via a pointer to [`unsigned`] `char`, as the code in this answer does, but, generally, you may not otherwise access an object via a pointer to a type incompatible with that object's.

Note also that the `printf` above is a bit sloppy.  In the event that `int16_t` is a different type from `int`, such as `short int`, the corresponding `printf` directive for it will have a length modifier in it -- likely `%hd`.  But because of details of the way `printf` is declared, it is the result of promoting `my_int` to `int` that will be passed to `printf`.  That rescues the mismatch, and in practice, the printed result will be the same as if you used the correct directive.

Comment: Interesting attention to spec with  "You might see a recommendation to use a pointer ..." and then casual  attention with `printf()`.  Recommend `printf("Int %d \n", (int) my_int);` or `printf("Int %" PRId16 " \n", my_int);`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, the code presented in the question is fully conforming, including with respect to the `printf` call, as already explained in the answer itself.  I intentionally chose this approach over the cast and especially over `PRId16` so as to avoid distracting the seemingly-inexperienced OP from the details that respond directly to the question.  I think throwing in `int16_t` may have already been a bit challenging.

Comment: Thank you all! @JohnBollinger your solution is what I asked for!